# Accounts Library: Serialization failed direction="Deserialize", expected Boolean but was SignedTransaction

Tags: corda

I'm using the **Accounts** library.

1. I create an account in my **first** node using: `flow start CreateAccount name: "adel"`
2. I try to retrieve that account by running a flow from my **second** node: `flow start GetAccountInfo uuid: "f8cf9d5c-ce4a-422a-af99-4e6563ac6536"`

**GetAccountInfo:**

```java
@StartableByRPC
public class GetAccountInfo extends FlowLogic<AccountInfo> {

    private UUID uuid;
    public GetAccountInfo(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = UUID.fromString(uuid);
    }
    public GetAccountInfo(UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    @Override
    public AccountInfo call() throws FlowException {

        // Get the host of all accounts
        Party accountsRegistry = getServiceHub().getIdentityService().wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(
                CordaX500Name.parse("O=Accounts-Registry,L=London,C=GB"));

        return subFlow(new RequestAccountInfo(uuid, accountsRegistry));
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
[ERROR] 12:23:17-0500 [Node thread-1] amqp.DeserializationInput.log - Serialization failed direction="Deserialize", type="java.lang.Boolean", msg="Described type with descriptor net.corda:7mttgXO2HdBLwATyV7pCpg== was expected to be of type class java.lang.Boolean but was class net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction", ClassChain="java.lang.Boolean" {actor_id=internalShell, actor_owning_identity=O=Tokens-Mint, L=London, C=GB, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=d0486083-decf-46fc-97eb-247923fce14f, invocation_id=a6bd568a-c834-48e6-b93b-9301609d59f1, invocation_timestamp=2019-08-27T17:23:15.546Z, origin=internalShell, session_id=c127adee-176e-454c-9777-5de852633e82, session_timestamp=2019-08-27T17:23:15.112Z, thread-id=220}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug - it's fixed on master. Will publish new JARs today. Cheers :)

Comment: I can confirm that the new version `1.0-RC02` fixed the issue.

Comment: Sorry I think I was too fast, I'm getting this error:
`java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/r3/corda/lib/ci/RequestKeyFlow`

Comment: You probably need to purge your gradle cache and make sure you are using the most up to date dependencies

Comment: **A.** The problem was that now we need to include `cordaCompile "$confidential_id_release_group:ci-workflows:$confidential_id_release_version"` in the `workflows` CordApp, this wasn't the case in `1.0-RC01`. I think this is an important part to add to the `README.md` file of the `Account Library` repo; under the `Adding accounts dependencies to an existing CorDapp` section. **B.** after fixing point A, I got `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: IdentityService.registerKeyToParty` so I had to upgrade to `corda_release_version = '4.3-SNAPSHOT'`.

Comment: Yes, you are right - sorry we need to update the docs. Will do that now!